How to include value labels when exporting tab output with "putexcel" in Stata?
I have a lot of categorical (Likert-scale) variables that I want to tabulate against three other variables, just showing the frequencies. For each of these two-way tabs, I would like to export the resulting table to Excel (because the rest of my team works in Excel) using the putexcel command. I have succesfully exported the frequency table to an excel file, but I am unable to also export the value labels, which I would like as column and row names. Let me illustrate:
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r18/auto2
    
tab rep78 foreign, matcell(freq) matrow(names) 
matrix list freq
matrix list names
return list
cd "$output" 
putexcel    set output.xlsx, sheet(rep78) replace 
putexcel    B2="Variable label as the title of the matrix"
putexcel    B4=matrix(freq), names

This gives me the following Excel output:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/CgEPm.png
How can I have the value labels of the two variables as row and column names of the table in Excel and the Variable label of one of the two variables as the title? Basically I want the table in Excel to look like the tab output in Stata. Thanks for your help!
